# How to create a rich text editor that returns html results in Flutter?

Tags: html, flutter, dart, rich-text-editor, flutter-packages

My goal is to create a rich text editor that returns html results. I am using the package [`flutter_quill`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill). It can only [return plain text using `_controller.document.toPlainText()` and json using `_controller.document.toDelta().toJson()`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill#input--output). I also tried [`html_editor_enhanced`](https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor_enhanced) before. It has some problems. When I click the text color button and the dialog is shown, I can't press one of the colors in the horizontal color list. The mouse is always a text mouse and I can enter text despite the dialog being displayed in front of the text field. Although the dialog is blocked, I can still write behind the text field. Also, I am using `web (Chrome)` to run the app. Are there any other rich text editors that can return html results or any way to return html results in [`flutter_quill`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_quill)? Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try https://pub.dev/packages/html_editor_enhanced

Comment: @SankethB.K I tried it before. It has some problems. When I click the text color button and the dialog is shown, I can't press one of the colors in the horizontal color list. The mouse is always a text mouse and I can enter text despite the dialog being displayed in front of the text field. Although the dialog is blocked, I can still write behind the text field.

Comment: Also, I am using `web (Chrome)` to run the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution!

I am using the following code to return html results:

```
final convertedValue = jsonEncode(delta.toJson());
final markdown = deltaToMarkdown(convertedValue);
final html = markdownToHtml(markdown);
```